# How to continuosly display updates to user browser WITHOUT user refreshing the browser

Tags: javascript

First, let me set the stage: I am a new user and this is my very first post. I normally play with Ruby to solve my simple problems which are the only type of problems I get into.
I have come across and issue for which 99% of the people tells me that I need to use JavaScript to solve it. Of course I don't know JavaScript and today I have spent over 8 hours reading about JavaScript's tutorials for beginners. After this long preamble, let me tell you what I need to do and perhaps the Stackoverflow community can recommend some tools or point me to the correct source.

I have a UNIX server generating a log 24x7 with information that is updated every second or faster. Every night we cut the log and a new log starts.
I wrote a simple application in Ruby using one of the Ruby popular GUI toolkits, shoes, and it works without a problem. From any desktop you can run the application which:

1. Connects to the UNIX server
2. Reads the latest updates from the log file
3. Displays the latest updates on a Dashboard without user intervention. The user only needs to start the application and from that point on it is refreshed every second automatically.

The problem with the above approach is that in order for anyone to use it, I need to install Ruby and all its requirements, including the toolkit on the person's desktop.

I would like to:

1. Write an application that will run on the server where the log is created.
2. Allow any user to connect via a browser (HTTP) pointing to my application's page
3. The user will walk away
4. My application will continuously, without human intervention, update the Dashboard (the page on the browser) that was opened by the user.
5. Any number of people with a browser should be able to do this simultaneously.

Can anyone point me to the correct technology that I need to use and perhaps some sample or code snippet?

Comment: For starters, look up AJAX.

Comment: Sounds like the perfect usecase for WebSockets (which might not be supported in older browsers, though)

Comment: Look up jQuery and AJAX

Answer (score 2):

**XMLHttpRequest()** object allows you to create a HTTP request to the server. The browser doesn't need to refresh, however the client needs to repetitively ask the server if something is new, so the network traffic is high anyway.

**WebSockets** are more suitable for you. Using node.js, you may create websocket server...

*server code*

```
var http = require('http');
var WebsocketServer = require("websocket").server;

var httpServer = http.createServer(function(){});
httpServer.listen(/*port*/ 9822, function(){});
var wsServer = new WebsocketServer({httpServer: httpServer});
```

...and communicate with clients

```
wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
  var connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);    

  // respond to client request
  connection.on('message', function(message) {
    connection.send(data);
  });

  // or create an event on the client without its request
  if(something) connection.send(data);
});
```

The client may use websockets to connect with server

*client code*

```
ws = new WebSocket('ws://' + server + ':9882');

// create request
ws.send(data);

// handle request
ws.onmessage = function(message) { ... }
```

See [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_websocket.htm) on websockets.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using AJAX and jQuery

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).

Then the server can push data when there is actually data to be pushed. No need to polling from client (saves bandwidth and updates are in real-time). It works with a standard HTTP connection (as well as HTTPS) that is upgraded to a socket connection.

As you state you are not familiar with Javascript (which is a must in either case) you can ease the "get started" curve by using one of the many wrapper libraries that use WebSocket (incl. fallback mode in case WebSocket is not supported in browser).

I would recommend you to read the [specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-websockets-20091222/) anyways to understand what goes on.

A couple of suggestions:
http://socket.io/
http://xsockets.net/

Personally I prefer [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki) but this require a .Net enabled server (it's however [compatible with Mono on Linux](http://blog.filipekberg.se/2012/12/10/running-signalr-on-mono/)).

Comment: As suggested, I will look into WebSocket. One thing I want the community to keep in mind, I don't want to install ANYTHING at all on the client's desktop. I want the client to type something like: http://my.appl:someport or something similar.

Comment: @user2491454 No need to install anything on client (everything is provided in the web page as html + javascript). WebSockets works over the normal http-protocol. If user doesn't have a browser that support websockets the script can fallback to ajax polling.

Comment: Great. Thank you. I will start playing with it. Also, I found that Ruby supports WebSockets. I will likely use Ruby and WebSocket as I feel more confident with Ruby.